# Can super Buddhists eat bread?

Tags: comparative-religion, food, religion

Bread has flour and yeast. Therefore, a scientist can say that it is both an animal and a vegetable grain. Is there anything wrong with eating bread?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, my ego is completely confused. Still, for the sake of satisfying it.

**Can super Buddhists eat bread?**

If by super buddhists, you mean as someone of so high calibur that s/he will be aware of the presence of any tiniest `living organism` whether it's yeast or something else-- No, that venerable one won't eat cause it's killing.

**Is there anything wrong with eating bread?**

Sorry, I don't know.

But atleast, I can give metta to self and others. :)

With Metta.
May all the tiny living beings that I ate unintentionally till now be free from their suffering. May I reach to the level of venerable one to identify any living microorganism with **mind**. May I be free from my remorse of eaten yeast. May they pardon me.

Answer (score 0):

No.
According to Buddhism, you required only to not to kill.
If someone or something is killed unintentionally it will not amount to killing